# In Checkers/Draughts, can a King jump multiple pieces and end up where it started?

Tags: checkers

title pretty much explains it, is the move depicted in the paint drawing I made legal?

I don't really see why it shouldn't be as it should theoretically follow all the conventional rules of checkers but I haven't really read anything specific about this situation and it's really hard to test it using online checker engines.

(English/American checker rules)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Board Games Stack Exchange! Great first question, especially with the image!

Comment: @Thunderforge Ha! Thanks, I always try to draw something if it helps in understanding the question, I'm not very good with words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing disallows this sequence of jumps. Pieces do not need to end on a different space to which they started the turn, kings are allowed to move and capture in any direction of play, and multiple jumps may be made if they are additional captures.

Further, if these were the only pieces on the board, or if no other pieces could have been captured off the square instead of continuing around the square: this move is not just legal, *but mandatory*.

If at any point there was an option to capture off the square, for example by continuing past the bottom corner to capture again in a straight line, the player moving the king may choose which capture to make, but they must make one of them.

Comment: Thanks for the clear and detailed answer, as I said in the question I suspected this was the case but now I got the confirmation I needed.

Thanks again!

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that even though jumped-over pieces are not removed until all jumps are complete, a piece which has been jumped over may not be jumped over again, even if it is still on the board.